# Via Ferrata with a bicycle

Tags: climbing, biking, trekking

I am going on a two week trip soon. We are two people, with bicycles and backpacks. Small sections of the trip pass through rocky trail with steel ropes. The weather is summer, but the possibility for downpours exists.

We have one climbing harness, a climbing carabiner, 15m of dynamic rope and a reverso. My worry is that shouldering/carrying on the back the bikes will be a balancing challenge, and the falls are significant.

Can we use our current equipment to make the passages safer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the passes are horizontal only, you might tie the bikes to the steel ropes and just push and/or pull them.

If it's a more or less vertical climb, I wouldn't do it with a bike.

In any case I wouldn't tie the bike to myself nor would I carry it on my shoulder. I would make sure my safety comes first. In case of a slip or in case of a fall I would make sure the bike won't make things worse by getting in the way of regaining equilibrium or, worse, accelerating my fall.

Comment: Some hikers advised us to disassemble the bikes and carry first the wheels, then the frames. But with all the fog and rain that day, we chickened out and descended the mountain.

Comment: Sounds to me like you did the best thing. I always encourage bailing out when in doubt. Wish more people did that.

Comment: Hiking's very safe, until it isn't.  There are plenty of places where a 45-60 degree slope goes on for way too long if you fall off.  Listen to your caution, plenty of folk regret not having done so.  I almost skidded off a series of switchbacks snowshoeing down a semi-melted trail cover.  It's a 60 degree deep ravine.  My buddy was all queasy about it and I said it wasn't a big deal:  he was right.